# Why is it not stopping?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a view bot. Just for recreational/personal use. The problem is I am trying to make it so it will only open 20 windows at a time. It won't work for some reason. I also want it to wait 2000 milliseconds before closing the process it generates and go into a loop. I have co1unt as an integer. Anyone help please?

```
Dim Co1unt As Integer = 0
Public Sub Refreshlist()
    Dim p As Process, co1unt As Integer, MyProgram As String = "iexplore"
    For Each p In Process.GetProcesses
        If p.ProcessName = MyProgram Then
            co1unt = co1unt + 1
            TextBox1.Text = co1unt
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Refreshlist()
    Do
        Refreshlist()
        If Co1unt < 20 Then
            Dim webAddress As String = ""
            Dim p1 As Process = Process.Start(webAddress)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
            p1.Kill()
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: "I used to be with **it**, but then they changed what **it** was. Now what I'm with isn't **it**, and what's **it** seems weird and scary to me." (that's a long way of asking for a more descriptive title).